# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.entitlements' dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, upgrade

Whenever i try sudo apt-get upgrade or try to install any other package i get the above error. Is there any way to solve it?? Using ubuntu 16.04

```
Removing python3-distro-info (0.14ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0~16.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.entitlements'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336425/no-module-named-uaclient-during-sudo-apt-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: i have already tried  and it didnot work

Answer (score 1):

You should install `opcua` and `opcua-client` with default python command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade opcua

python -m pip install --upgrade opcua-client
```

Comment: second command fails on opening README.md with complain about wrong encoding
`      File "/tmp/pip-build-_JmC0n/asyncua/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        with open(path.join(this_directory, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and try to solve then it work for me.

My environment:

- OS: ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- python version: 3.6.9(system default) , manual
  install 3.8.7

System python path have been link to python 3.8 when I install python 3.8, so any process use python will call python 3.8 and use pip3.8 site-packages, not use system dist-packages(python 3.6). But python 3.8 uaclinet(install by pip) is different from uaclinet in dist-packages(ubuntu-advantage-tools provide). then I  use apt upgrade

```
設定 ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~18.04.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.entitlements'
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
處理時發生錯誤：
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, I copy the uaclinet(in dist-packages) to python 3.8 site-packages and run upgrade again,  then  it works( maybe has compatibility problems )

```
設定 ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.0.2~18.04.1) ...
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
   Affected packages: ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64
```

I think if your use system python , you can use comment by `Jan Wilamowski`,

Comment: I have the same scenario. Where can i find uaclinet (dist-package)?

Comment: @diogenes_vz ubuntu system python dist-packages path is  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Comment: Why does python have any effect on apt. Shouldn't it work on a system that doesn't have python?

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared for me after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04.

I updated opcua and opcua-client as suggested with python -m pip install, and also with pip3 install, to get it updated in python3 packages, and the problem remained.
I have system python3 installed in /usr/bin/python3 (version 3.6), and another version in /usr/local/bin/python3 (version 3.8) which is the default python3.  I'm not sure why, but the uaclient.entitlements module can be loaded properly with /usr/bin/python3, but not with /usr/local/bin/python3

Instead of changing the location of the uaclient package, the following worked for me:

I used update-alternatives to choose which python3 will be used by default, either system python3 which is /usr/bin/python3.6, or the updated python3 which is installed in /usr/local/bin/python3.8 as described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.8 2
```

Then, choose /usr/bin/python3.6 as the default by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

A symlink is created as /etc/alternatives/python3 that points to the chosen default python3.

Since the way I set the alternatives results in /usr/local/bin/python3.8 as the automatic default python3, the symlink /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6 is removed.  But this symlink is still needed for dependencies/functions that use system python through /usr/bin/python3, so I added back the sym link:

```
sudo ln -s python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

By setting /usr/bin/python3.6 as the default instead of /usr/local/bin/python3.8, then uaclient.entitlements can be loaded properly.  This worked for me to install and upgrade packages where this uaclient.entitlements ModuleNotFoundError was occurring.  Just have to switch back to using /usr/local/bin/python3.8 when finished installing.  But I think now that ubuntu-advantage-tools is configured by getting through this error, there doesn't seem to be a need to switch to /usr/bin/python3.6 as the default anymore for installing packages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336425/no-module-named-uaclient-during-sudo-apt-upgrade-ubuntu-16-04 worked for me. Basically,  I modified manually the post-installation and pre-remove script in /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.postinst and /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm and replace python3 with the complete path /usr/bin/python3.5, and then the 'apt-get upgrade' didn't fail as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use ubuntu advantage tools then

```
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

but even tat failed for me... I had to

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/ubuntu-advantage-tools.prerm
```

because this script was blocking uninstall

i have tried to install:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade opcua
python -m pip install --upgrade opcua-client
```

but even that was failing for me on a second - client installation

finally after about 6 months I can do ubuntu update without error reporting.